# Rvalue copy and and assignment for secure array class

Tags: c++, c++11, cryptography

I have a C++03 library with lots of classes. I'm interested in trying to take advantage of Rvalues and move semantics under C++11 for two or three critical classes. Once of the critical classes is a `SecBlock`, which is effectively a secure array class. It has a secure allocator and deallocator, and its used nearly everywhere.

`SecBlock` looks like so, where `T` might be a `byte` or an `int`:

```
template <class T, class A = AllocatorWithCleanup<T> >
class SecBlock
{
   ...
private:
    A m_alloc;
    size_type m_size;
    T *m_ptr;
}
```

***If*** I am reading [Thomas Becker's "C++ Rvalue References"](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) treatise correctly, I can use a simple `swap` because `SecBlock` does not have a base class (no need for `Base(std::move(rhs))`:

```
template <class T, class A = AllocatorWithCleanup<T> >
class SecBlock
{
   ...

#if CXX11_AVAILABLE
    SecBlock(SecBlock&& t)
    {
        std::swap(*this, t);
    }
    SecBlock& operator=(SecBlock&& t)
    {
        if(this != &t)
            std::swap(*this, t);
        return *this;
    }
#endif

private:
    A m_alloc;
    size_type m_size;
    T *m_ptr;
}
```

We guard on `CXX11_AVAILABLE` because the library is a C++03 library at heart.

It's probably obvious I have some open questions. For instance, do I have to guard for self assignment in `operator=`? (I suspect not, but I think its best to show the code and take the comments).

I'm also interested in knowing if a derived class must implement the semantics also, even if they add no members.

Is the code above correct, or are there gaps that need to be addressed? If there are gaps, what are they?

Comment: Note [tag:crypto++] is synonymized with [tag:cryptography].

Comment: @Mast: they are two different things. One is a field of study, the other is a software library. Intuitively, they cannot be used interchangeably in a sentence, so they are clearly not synonyms.

Comment: This discussion has been held before: [Current synonymization of crypto++](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/current-synonymization-of-crypto). We will not have this discussion in comments.

Comment: @Mast - I'm not interested in a discussion about it. In the previous question, I simply asked what I should do because I was receiving inappropriate/unwanted emails due to the intersection with the notification system. The discussion you folks had about it was irrelevant to me because you discussed something I ***did not*** ask. In this question I simply pointed out the errant behavior to let folks know it was not me mis-classifying the question. In both cases, I'm not interested in a discussion.

Comment: Somewhat related, definitely worth the read, nevertheless: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/1198654

Comment: Voting to close clearly off topic.

Comment: @jww: Don't be rude and take the advice about crypto++. Does not matter what you think. These are the rules the community has set up. Follow them or find an alternative community to play in.

Answer (score 3):

This code does not function.

Let's take a look at your move constructor:

```
SecBlock(SecBlock&& t)
{
    std::swap(*this, t);
}
```

This caused a stack overflow on my system. Why? Imagine if the swap function was implemented like this:

```
template <typename T>
void swap (T &t1, T &t2)
{
    T temp = std::move (t1) ;
    t1 = std::move (t2) ;
    t2 = std::move (temp) ;
}
```

In fact, this is how it is implemented by Visual Studio 2012. The first line `T temp = std::move (t1) ;`, calls your move constructor. This causes you to recursively call your move constructor until your program inevitably crashes.

Another problem is that before the swap, `m_size` and `m_ptr` for `*this` will be uninitialized. So even if you fixed your move constructor, you will be transferring uninitialized data to `t`. Assuming you're destructor does some clean-up, this could lead to undefined behavior.

All in all, both member-functions are a mess.
Check out the [rule of 5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for more help.

Comment: Now I'm in a bad spot. The question may violate the site's policies on working, bug free code. What should I do with it? Delete it, or leave it and accept your answer? (Sorry to ask. I don't make it to these parts often).

Comment: @jww Give it time I guess. If it violates this site's rules, then I imagine the question will eventually be closed. If it doesn't violate the rules, then wait for more answers and select the best one.

Comment: *"This code does not function...."* - oh, my. It tested OK on OS X. I did not start a testing cycle on Lnux, BSD or Windows. I was waiting for feedback before the testing cycle. Thank you very much. I just learned a tremendous amount about these things...

Comment: I see what happened here.... Apple/Clang claimed 201103L, but failed a feature test. When it failed a feature test, the code path was not activated. When I cut-int `std::move` without the guards to test your findings, it could not even compile. OS X is the pits. I'm jumping over to Fedora 22 and the GCC 5.1 compiler.

Comment: @jww, if an answer finds a bug in your code, it doesn't automatically makes the question of-topic (in fact it happens quite often that bugs are found by reviews!) If **to the best of the asker's knowledge** the code is working, then it is on topic. This is the case with your question. You thought it was correct, but a review found a bug. Great thing you asked for code review!